# Entity Framework with .NET 4.0 many to many Association

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I am new to .NET and EF and I'm working on an application that requires dynamic querying of the entities.
I have a db with 3 tables:

```
**Employee**      **EmployeeSkills**      **Skill**
Employee_ID       Id                      Skill_ID
Name              Employee_ID             Name
Address           Skill_ID                etc.
etc.              Level
```

I will be  sending from my client property names for selecting and dictionaries with property-value pairs for filtering, for example {"name", "skill",[{"skillId="1"},{"level=2"}]} will return  all employees having the skill assoctiated with id 1 and konoledge of this skill at level 2.

I really need to design my entities so that the queries are as simple as possible, meaning no joins or complex sql's. I already managed to implement everything for selecting and filtering properties but I'm still struggling with many-to-many relationships.

I know that if my intermediary table would have only the Employee_ID and Skill_ID fields then i could just reference the skills using Employee.Skills.Is there any way to to this using my current table structure?

I'm hoping there is some kind of mapping, like defining some kind of navigation properties on the Employee entity that stores the query required to get all the Skills of an Employee with their Level.

P.S. I'm using VS 2012, EF runtime version 4.0.3, version 4.4.0

Comment: I don't like it when EF hides my intermediate tables, I prefer to have joins where I can see what is actually happening.

Answer (score 2):

If you use codefirst approach, you can configure your relationship with Fluent API:

```
HasMany(e => e.Skills).WithMany(s=>s.Employees).Map(se =>
            {
                se.MapLeftKey("Skill_ID");
                se.MapRightKey("Employee_ID");
                se.ToTable("EmployeeSkills");
            });
```

**Update** In DB-First approach, you cannot configure navigation properties in your case.
[This is link where yu can read what you can do in your situation.](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/)

Comment: Hello, we are generating our entities from an existing db.

Comment: It is pity, in db-first approach you cannot do what you want. This is link where yu can read what you can do in your situation: http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/

Comment: Is there a way to do this kind of mapping after the generation from the db? If i could just generate my own "virtual "properties for an entity it would be perfect. Virtual property meaning a property defined only in the entity, that is not saved in the db. For example generate the virtual property skills which returns a list of skills names and levels.

Comment: I am afraid it cannot be done :( You should use navigation properties EmployeeSkills to work with it, or use Code-First approach for database mapping. (CodeFirst means that mapping is in code. It can be done for existing database).

Comment: That's what I need, if it can be done for existing db than it's perfect.Where should I do the mapping?

Comment: Not so easy. But you can read about codefirst here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Hi, if I would to regenerate my db from code first could i implement something like public virtual ICollection<Qualification> Qualifications and provide a custom implemenetation to the get method?

Comment: What exactly do you want that method to do?

Comment: to return a collection of Qualifications.After I've done that i'll try to figure out how i can return a custom object that contains a Qualification and the Level.